# jqgrid - 'setCell' is not working in Frozen column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which has frozen columns. I have to update the cell value in a frozen column but it is not working.

Here is the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/5/

**HTML**

```
<table id="sg2"></table>
<div id="psg2"></div>

 <br>

<button type='button' id="SetGrid2">Update 'client' in first row of Grid 2</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery("#sg2").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoencode: true,
    width:500,
    height: 'auto',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollrows: true,
    loadui: 'disable',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int",frozen: true },
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date",frozen: true },
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,frozen: true },
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    caption: "Grid 2 - with Frozen columns"
}).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');

var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test 1234567890123456789",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
        ];

for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    jQuery("#sg2").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);


$('#SetGrid2').on('click', function(){
    jQuery("#sg2").jqGrid('setCell', 1, 'name', 'Updated');
});
```

I am using 'setCell' functionality in jqgrid to set the cell value. If the frozen property is removed from that column or if the column is sorted, I am seeing the new value.

Am I missing anything specific to frozen column?

Environment: jqgrid plugin 4.6.0, IE 9

**Solution applied:**

In my case, I was not able to update the jqGrid plugin to latest. So, destroyed and set the frozen column as a workaround and it worked great.

```
           myGrid.jqGrid('destroyFrozenColumns');

           if (rowData.Id == 0) {
               myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'Edit', 'New');
           }
           else {
               myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'Edit', null);
           }

           myGrid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [unclear from the wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns), but frozen columns cannot be edited (including by the `setCell` function.)

This can be handled by unfreezing the columns, setting the cell value, then freezing them again at the end of your 'click' event:

```
$('#SetGrid2').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#sg2').jqGrid('destroyFrozenColumns');
    var cell = jQuery("#sg2").jqGrid('setCell', 1, 'name', 'Updated');
    jQuery('#sg2').jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/99x50s2s/18/)

**[Note for posterity]** - If you want to dynamically change what columns are frozen, you do so similarly by unfreezing - setting/unsetting frozen - then refreezing, but you also have to call `trigger`.

```
// freezes the amount col as well...
$('#SetGrid2').on('click', function(){
   jQuery("#sg2")
   .jqGrid('destroyFrozenColumns')
   .jqGrid('setColProp','amount', {frozen:true})
   .jqGrid('setFrozenColumns')
   .trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}])
});
```

[Another Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/99x50s2s/21/)

Comment: Thanks for the code and information. I like the idea of destroying and setting the frozen columns again.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. jqGrid 4.6.0 don't support `setCell`, `setRowData` and cell or inline editing in combination with frozen columns. I implemented the feature in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) only recently (after  publishing of free jqGrid 4.8). I have improved essentially the performance of frozen columns additionally.

You can verify that the modified demo  https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/99x50s2s/9/ works correctly.

I recommend you don't fill the grid using `addRowData` and to use `data: mydata` instead. Additionally you should use `idPrefix` (with different values for both grids) if you fill more as one grid with the same rowids:

```js
idPrefix: "g1_",
```

You can of case use many new features of free jqGrid. [The wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)  https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/99x50s2s/11/